# WCF service hosted on windows service not working on server

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, wcf, service

I have a windows service working perfect. But when I deploy it on Windows server 2012, I am not able to browse it.

> This page can’t be displayed
>
> - Make sure the web address https://localhost is correct.
> - Look for the page with your search engine.
> - Refresh the page in a few minutes.

p.s I don't have IIS installed on the server. Do we need that as I am hosting it in a Windows service.

Comment: If you're self-hosting in a Windows service, then you *do not* need IIS installed

Comment: First of all check the first bullet ;-) you said, you deployed the service on a server, but you're browsing to a _localhost_ address. Do you do this while being remotely connected to that server? Then it may be ok. If you're trying to browse it from your developer machine then you'll have to use the server's name like https:// yourserver/. Next thing: Are you sure it's scheme _https_ not _http_?

Comment: I am trying to browse it locally in server. As base address I added is local host.

Somehow I insta iis and it's working...dnt knw why